# How to see the content of the combobox with the selection of a gridview's row?

Tags: c#

When I select a row in my grid, I want to see the content of the column 'ProductCategory' in my cboCat, but I don't see anything, the column 'ProductCategory' is from another table. I only see the first row of my items.

I'm able to see the content in my other controls, but I can't see the actual value in my cboCat. I don't know if I do something wrong?

Ex : If the 'ProductCategory' column contains the value NGC, I want to see NGC in my cboCat. Is there a cboCat.Value?

P.S. This fonction is from the SelectionChanged event form the gridview

[image] As you can see on the picture, I select a row in my MetroGrid and the category is Wii, but in my cboCat I see NGC, it's the same for all the others rows of my MetroGrid

Here's my code :

```
private void Remplir_Champs(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (gridProduits.CurrentRow != null && gridProduits.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem != null)
        {
            ProductDisplay proDis = (ProductDisplay)gridProduits.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
            Category category = db.Categories.First(c => c.CategoryName == proDis.ProductCategory);

            //Product pro = db.Products.Single(prod => prod.Category.CategoryName == proDis.ProductCategory);

            txtNom.Text = proDis.ProductName;
            numQteTot.Value = (proDis.ProductQteUsed + proDis.ProductQteNew);
            txtDesc.Text = proDis.ProductDesc;
            cboCat.SelectedItem = category;
            numQteUsed.Value = proDis.ProductQteUsed;
            numQteNew.Value = proDis.ProductQteNew;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to provide more details, explain your problem so that people can understand what is the problem exactly and what is the desired behavior.

Comment: Is it ok? I made some updates?

Comment: what is cboCat displaying with this code? Are there items in cboCat? Are the product ID the same as the cbo's indexes?

Comment: It would help if you could also add some of the UI code

Comment: sorry for the delay, @loli I'm now able to see the text values in my cboCat with some fixes

Comment: can you try `cboCat.Text = category.toString();` (assuming category.toString() returns WII)

Comment: it's not working, the content of my combobox doesn't change. Is there an event I'm supposed to place on my cboCat? like selectionChanged or something like that?

Comment: From what I understand `cboCat` is a `ComboBox`. What you probably need to do is find a matching item and set it to `SelectedItem` or set the selected item index. So try something like `cboCat.SelectedItem = cboCat.Items.FirstOrDefault(item=>item.CategoryName == proDis.ProductCategory);` or whatever the matching property that you can use for comparing the two.